# PDO - Query no funciona cuando utilizo bindValue

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy teniendo un problema que no logro entender del todo.

Tengo una query que funcionaba hasta hace un dia y de repente ha dejado de funcionar
el codigo en cuestion es el siguiente:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE currency = :currency;');
$query->bindValue(':currency', $currency, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

en este caso cuando trato de hace un `var_dump` del resultado obtengo lo siguiente :

```
var_dump($query->rowCount());  // int(0)
$array = [];
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $array[] = $row;
}
var_dump($array); // Array(0) { }
```

Cambiando la query en la misma identica funcion, simplemente escribiendo yo el valor en la query:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE currency = "EUR";');
$query->execute();
```

y vuelvo a hacer el mismo proceso

```
var_dump($query->rowCount());  // int(7)
$array = [];
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $array[] = $row;
}
var_dump($array); // Array(7) { ... }
```

Obtengo los datos que necesito..me estoy equivocando en algo? como dije al principio me funciono hasta ayer

Comment: ¿Probaste forzando el valor de la moneda `$currency='EUR'` antes de `bindValue()`?.

Comment: estaba dentro de una funcion `function getByCurrency($currency = 'EUR')`, despues de varios `var_dump` me di cuenta que $currency en todos casos llegaba vacio .. asique resolvi implementando un `if(empty($currency))` antes de proceder a la ejecucion de la query. Gracias de todos modos !